# Не идет обучение нейросети ML Net

Tags: .net

Добавляю в каталог две папки с картинками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбираю каталог Animals. Он по началу скачивал какую-то библиотеку. Потом просто ничего не происходит. В логах пусто. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Если отменить обучение, то появляется ошибка.

```
    в Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService.Experiments.LocalAutoMLExperiment.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/Experiments/LocalAutoMLExperiment.cs:строка 202
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLEngine.<StartTrainingAsync>d__21.MoveNext() в /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/AutoMLEngineService/AutoMLEngine.cs:строка 161
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло восстановление vs через установщик.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]